# Update reference number in different texts

Tags: javascript, html

### What I have?

I have following array:

```
[
  {
    "position": 0,
    "text": "Some text",
    "children": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "text": "Some text REF#1.2"
      },
      {
        "position": 1,
        "text": "Some text"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "position": 1,
    "text": "Some text REF#1",
    "children": [
      {
        "position": 0,
        "text": "Some text"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### The Markup

Following markup is generated by above array (basically tree-like structure). Rows can be dragged-dropped and backend updates the positions accordingly *(sub-rows cannot be dragged out of parent)*.

[image]

### The generated HTML (using ReactJS)

```
<body>
  <div class="draggable">
    <div class="text">1.</div>
    <div class="description">Some text</div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="draggable">
        <div class="text">1.1</div>
        <div class="description">Some text REF#1.2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="draggable">
        <div class="text">1.2</div>
        <div class="description">Some text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable">
    <div class="text">2.</div>
    <div class="description">Some text REF#1</div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="draggable">
        <div class="text">2.1</div>
        <div class="description">Some text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### The requirement

- The `text` field can refer some section using `REF#X.X` format. The requirement is to update this static text, if any row is dragged and the position is updated. So, let's say `#1.2` row is dragged to the top, then `#1.1` *(which will be `#1.2` after dragging)* text should be now "Some text `REF#1.1`".
- Or if `#2` is dragged before `#1`, then `#2`'s text should be "Some text `REF#2`" and `#1.1` text should be updated to "Some text `REF#2.2`" as `#1` is now `#2` after dragging.

### What's my thinking?

What I think could be done is to save previous positions before sending to backend and once we have the updated positions from the API, then compare the both text and positions with previous positions and update any text if it references. Basically, I am trying to find an optimized way of achieving this and any hints or general pseudo code would be perfect.

Comment: No, the _markup_, that is the generated HTML code, _not the rendered view_. CSS could do what you need, take a look at [counter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter) and [::marker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker).

Comment: @Teemu I don't think you understand the question, I have asked to update the reference in static text inside the description.

Comment: I've understood the question, it should be possible to use the above mentioned CSS properties with [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to achieve what you need. You've to modify the generator, though.

Comment: Do you have access to backend?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to BE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a observer pattern, using the objects with REF in text as listeners. When the "change position" event trigger, call the children "change position" too.